# Derivative of $|x|^p$

Tags: real-analysis

What is the derivative of $x\in \mathbb{R}\mapsto|x|^p$ if, $1\leq p<\infty$ ?

Is it $C^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Do we have problem in $0$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you compute its derivative in $[0, +\infty[$? In $]-\infty, 0]$? Can you compare the limits at 0?

Answer (score 3):

$|x| = x \cdot sgn(x)$ where $sgn$ is the signum function. So
$$(|x|^p)'=((x \cdot sgn(x))^p)' = (x\cdot sgn(x))'\cdot p(x\cdot sgn(x))^{p-1} = (x'\cdot sgn(x)+x\cdot sgn'(x))\cdot p|x|^{p-1} = p \cdot sgn(x)\cdot |x|^{p-1}$$

The derivation is not defined for $x=0$ and $p=1$, so it's not an element of $C^1(\Bbb{R})$ when $p=1$. Else the derivation is defined and it is an ellement of $C^1(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: If $p=2$ then $\vert\cdot\vert^p\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: That was a mistake. I corrected that.

Comment: It works for $p \geq 2$, even for odd ones, because $(x^p)'(0) = 0 = (-x^p)'(0)$

Comment: Yeah, noticed aswell, unfortunately too late! Sorry for that, already deleted my comment! :)

Answer (score 0):

We can attempt to differentiate by using the chain rule.
$$\frac{d}{dx}|x|^p = p|x|^{p-1}\frac{d}{dx}|x|$$
$$=\begin{cases}
p|x|^{p-1} & x \geq 0\\
-p|x|^{p-1} & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
The left and right hand limits match for all $p>1$  So, the function is not differentiable at $0$ only for $p=1$.

Comment: Take a look at situation when $x=0$. If $p \geq 2$, the derivation is 0 at 0.

Comment: So the derivative is $|x|^{p-2}x$ in case $p\neq 1$